# Calling crypt32.dll CryptProtectData method from native code

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, cryptoapi

I'm trying to call into the **crypt32.dll** method **CryptProtectData** from managed code, but I do not seem to have the marshaling types quite right in my delegate's declaration:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate bool CryptProtectDataDelegate(
    IntPtr pDataIn,             // DATA_BLOB*
    //StringBuilder szDataDescr,  // LPCWSTR
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string szDataDescr,   // LPCWSTR
    IntPtr pOptionalEntropy,    // DATA_BLOB*
    int pvReserved,             // PVOID 
    IntPtr pPromptStruct,       // CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT*
    int dwFlags,                // DWORD 
    IntPtr pDataOut             // DATA_BLOB*
);
```

which when invoked,

```
bool theResult = cryptProtectData(
    pDataIn,
    null,
    IntPtr.Zero,    // null,
    0,              // null,
    IntPtr.Zero,    // null,
    flag,
    pDataOut);
```

causes the exception

> +CryptProtectDataDelegate::Invoke' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the
>   unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and
>   parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged
>   signature.'

The native definition for `CryptProtectData` is

```
DPAPI_IMP BOOL CryptProtectData(
  DATA_BLOB                 *pDataIn,
  LPCWSTR                   szDataDescr,
  DATA_BLOB                 *pOptionalEntropy,
  PVOID                     pvReserved,
  CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT *pPromptStruct,
  DWORD                     dwFlags,
  DATA_BLOB                 *pDataOut
);
```

where DPAPI_IMP is defined as

```
#define DPAPI_IMP DECLSPEC_IMPORT
```

**I'm note sure what the legal type representations are that I should be using for the parameters in the delegate definition?**

Assuming `PVOID` is a **`void *`**, I found some documentation which suggests that it could be represented as an `int`, and b/c it can be *`null`*, I set it to *`0`* (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior).

---

Below is what should be a complete and run-able example (that will crash)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CallNativeDLLs
{
    static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
    }

    class Program
    {
        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        private delegate bool CryptProtectDataDelegate(
            IntPtr pDataIn,             // DATA_BLOB*
            //StringBuilder szDataDescr,  // LPCWSTR
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string szDataDescr,   // LPCWSTR
            IntPtr pOptionalEntropy,    // DATA_BLOB*
            int pvReserved,             // PVOID 
            IntPtr pPromptStruct,       // CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT*
            int dwFlags,                // DWORD 
            IntPtr pDataOut             // DATA_BLOB*
        );

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(@"c:\windows\system32\crypt32.DLL");

            IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "CryptProtectData");

            var cryptProtectData = (CryptProtectDataDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(
                pAddressOfFunctionToCall,
                typeof(CryptProtectDataDelegate));

            IntPtr pDataIn = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("hi");
            int flag = (int)0x4; //CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE 
            var pDataOut = new IntPtr();

            // EXCEPTION thrown here
            bool theResult = cryptProtectData(
                pDataIn,
                null,
                IntPtr.Zero,    // null,
                0,              // null,
                IntPtr.Zero,    // null,
                flag,
                pDataOut);

            bool result = NativeMethods.FreeLibrary(pDll);

            Console.WriteLine(theResult);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** Using **Amy's** link, the following runs (though I haven't tried decrypting the string yet, and CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE is weak)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CallNativeDLLs
{
    static class NativeMethods
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct DATA_BLOB
        {
            public int cbData;
            public IntPtr pbData;
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum CryptProtectPromptFlags
        {
            CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPT_ON_UNPROTECT = 0x1,
            CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPT_ON_PROTECT = 0x2
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum CryptProtectFlags
        {
            CRYPTPROTECT_UI_FORBIDDEN = 0x1,
            CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x4,
            CRYPTPROTECT_CRED_SYNC = 0x8,
            CRYPTPROTECT_AUDIT = 0x10,
            CRYPTPROTECT_NO_RECOVERY = 0x20,
            CRYPTPROTECT_VERIFY_PROTECTION = 0x40
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT
        {
            public int cbSize;
            public CryptProtectPromptFlags dwPromptFlags;
            public IntPtr hwndApp;
            public String szPrompt;
        }

        [DllImport("Crypt32.dll",
            SetLastError = true,
            CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]     
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool CryptProtectData(
            ref DATA_BLOB pDataIn,
            String szDataDescr,
            ref DATA_BLOB pOptionalEntropy,
            IntPtr pvReserved,
            ref CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT pPromptStruct,
            CryptProtectFlags dwFlags,
            ref DATA_BLOB pDataOut
        );
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr pbData = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("hi");
            var pDataIn = new NativeMethods.DATA_BLOB{cbData=0,pbData=pbData};
            var pOptionalEntropy = new NativeMethods.DATA_BLOB();
            var pPromptStruct = new NativeMethods.CRYPTPROTECT_PROMPTSTRUCT();
            var pDataOut = new NativeMethods.DATA_BLOB();

            bool theResult = NativeMethods.CryptProtectData(
                ref pDataIn,
                null,
                ref pOptionalEntropy, // null,
                IntPtr.Zero,          // null,
                ref pPromptStruct,    // null,
                NativeMethods.CryptProtectFlags.CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                ref pDataOut);

            Console.WriteLine(theResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help?  https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/crypt32.cryptprotectdata

Comment: I've just tried it on my machine, and I don't know why, but it crashes for me if my C# project is a tradition .NET application, but not if it's a .NET Core application. Mind you, ``theResult`` is false, so I don't know if it's actually working.

Comment: @Amy Kind of, I guess : ) Thanks I've been researching all day.

Comment: This function is already wrapped by the .NET Framework, ProtectedData.Protect() method.  The how-to is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection  Source code is here: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Security/system/security/cryptography/dataprotection.cs,36

Comment: Your code fails because you pass, for the 1st parameter, a pointer to a string instead of a pointer to a DATA_BLOB structure.

Comment: BTW, sizeof(PVOID) != sizeof(DWORD) != sizeof(int), IMHO better use IntPtr there. Also [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]  I am not an expert, but according to the prototype_BOOL
**WINAPI**
CryptProtectData(...), and usually **WINAPI** -- defines as stdcall